# How to implement an efficient image compressing?

Tags: android, image

I would like to compress images before uploaded and hosted on storage reference. Is there any way to achieve this efficiently ?

Even if quality will not be the best, the point is to reduce the size .

```
private void StoringImageToFirebaseStorage()
    {

        String uri = PostsImagesRefrence.child("Post Images").child(ImageUri.getLastPathSegment() + postRandomName + ".jpg").toString();

        StorageReference filePath = PostsImagesRefrence.child("Post Images").child(ImageUri.getLastPathSegment() + postRandomName + ".jpg");

        filePath.putFile(ImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task){
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                    SavingInformationToDatabase();
                }
                else
                {.....}
    }

private void OpenGallery() {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, Gallery_Pick);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode==Gallery_Pick && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null{
            ImageUri = data.getData();
            PostImage.setImageURI(ImageUri);
            PostImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    OpenGallery();
                {...}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use this simple light weight library to compress your images in any size you want and it will also help you to upload those images directly in bytes to firebase.

[Image Compressor](https://github.com/rjchakraborty/ImageCompressor)

```
  new ImageCompressor(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), imageFilePath, new ImageCompressListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onImageCompressed(byte[] outputImageBaos, File imageFile) {
                                if (outputImageBaos != null) {
                                    final StorageReference mediaFileRef = mStoreRef.child("images/" + imageFilePath);
                                    currenTask = mediaFileRef.putBytes(outputImageBaos);

                                    currenTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                throw task.getException();
                                            }

                                            // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                                            return mediaFileRef.getDownloadUrl();
                                        }
                                    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                String downloadUri = task.getResult().toString();

                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                    currenTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            sendProgressBroadcast(AppConstants.UPLOAD_FAILED, -1);
                                        }
                                    }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onProgress(com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                            int progress = (int) ((100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                                            sendProgressBroadcast(AppConstants.UPLOAD_PROGRESS, progress);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
```